# How do I access a struct that is in my node in my queue? C

Tags: c, struct, queue

So I have a queue implemented as a link list in which each node's data is a struct that stores a bunch of stuff but I want to access the string.

I'll post my code below, but I create and manage the queue in a separate queue.c file that is included in my main.c file. From which I pass the struct connection to to store the connections in a queue.

So I'm trying to make sure I actually am storing this correctly in my queue, but I don't know how to access it.

On line 90, I tried doing...

```
    printf("%s",networkQueue->front.Connection.ipAddress);
```

But it gives an error of...

```
networkManager2.c:90:33: error: request for member ‘Connection’ in something not a structure or union
  printf("%s",networkQueue->front.Connection.ipAddress);
                                 ^
```

So I'm wondering how I can access the stuff in my queue, I think I'm just getting real mixed up with all the different pointers and such.

networkManager2.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "queue.h"
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct connection
{
    /*
    IP Address can be stored in two formats, IPv4 or IPv6. 
    IPv4 is 15 chars long and of the format ###.###.###.### in regular digits
    IPv6 is 25 chars long and of the format ####:####:####::####:### in hex
    */
    char* ipAddress[26];
    int port; //port value from 0-65535
    char* protocolType[2];
    union
    {
        char* connectionName[6]; //UDP only, 5 letter name to the connection
        int hops; //TCP only, 0-255 declaring the number of hops for the connection.
    }protocol;  
};

/*
Defines Connection as a type struct connection
*/
typedef struct 
{
    char* ipAddress[26];
    int port;
    char* protocolType[2];
    union
    {
        char* connectionName[6]; 
        int hops; 
    }protocol;  
} Connection;

Connection* processConnection()
{
    /*
    Where the information for the connection is input.
    */
    Connection *currentConnection = malloc(sizeof(Connection));
    printf("IP Address: ");
    gets(currentConnection->ipAddress);
    printf("Protocol Type: ");
    gets(currentConnection->protocolType);
    printf("Port: ");
    scanf(" %d", &currentConnection->port);

    /*
    Depending on the protocol type, it stores hops or connection name.
    */
    if(strcmp(currentConnection->protocolType, "TCP") == 0)
    {
        printf("Hops: ");
        scanf(" %d", &currentConnection->protocol.hops);
    }
    else if(strcmp(currentConnection->protocolType, "UDP") == 0)
    {
        printf("Connection Name: ");
        scanf(" %s",&currentConnection->protocol.connectionName);
    }

    return currentConnection;
}

/*
This stores all the connections within a linked list queue. 
It takes in the queue that was created within the main, and also the new 
connection it wishes to add to the queue. It sends this to manage queue 
function from the queue.c file. 
*/
void storeConnection(Connection *incomingConnection, Queue *networkQueue)
{
    manageNetworkQueue(networkQueue,incomingConnection);
    printf("%s",networkQueue->front.Connection.ipAddress);
}

int main()
{
    int running = 0; //variable to check if the user wants to input more connections
    char* holder[1];
    Queue *networkQueue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    *networkQueue = createNetworkQueue();

    /*
    Inputs connections and stores them in an array of connections. The array can
    only hold up to 5 connections and replaces the oldest each time if its full. 
    */
    do
    {
        Connection *incomingConnection = processConnection();
        storeConnection(incomingConnection, networkQueue);

        printf("Continue?: ");
        scanf(" %d",&running);
        gets(holder); //avoid the scanf problem.
    }while(running == 0);
    free(networkQueue);
}
```

queue.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct node
{
    void *Connection;
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct Queue
{
    struct node *front;
    struct node *end;
}Queue;

Queue createNetworkQueue(Queue *networkQueue)
{
    networkQueue->front=NULL;
    networkQueue->end=NULL;
    return *networkQueue;
}

void manageNetworkQueue(Queue *networkQueue, void *incomingConnection)
{
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(networkQueue->front = NULL)
    {
        networkQueue->front=newNode;
        networkQueue->end=newNode;
        newNode->Connection=incomingConnection;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        newNode->previous=NULL;
    }else
    {
        newNode->Connection=incomingConnection;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        newNode->previous=networkQueue->end;
        networkQueue->end->next=newNode;
        networkQueue->end=newNode;
    }
}
```

queue.h

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_

struct node
{
    void *Connection;
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct Queue
{
    struct node *front;
    struct node *end;
}Queue;

Queue createNetworkQueue();
void manageNetworkQueue(Queue *networkQueue, void *incomingConnection);

#endif
```

EDIT: The comments aren't really up to date btw.

Comment: `void *Connection;` Connection type is `void` you have to cast it

Comment: `front` is pointer. `.` change to `->`

Comment: I think memory allocated by using malloc is not freed properly. free(networkQueue)  will not freed all the nodes inside the the queue. you have to take care of freeing all the nodes inside the network Queue